# sql table not updating on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-applications

The following code is from a details page that receives a querystring from another page and then loads the details based on that id passed. That works fine, but now my problem is that the save changes button does not seem to be doing what it should be; the page just flashes like it submitted and loads all the values back, I've debugged and it all goes through fine, what could be the issue? Could it have something to do with me using querystring, because I have another update command on another page (no querystring) and it works perfectly...

```
    namespace CC
{
    public partial class customerdetails : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int customerID = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customerID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            string strConnString2 = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString2))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerStatus, CustomerGroup, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, CompanyName, CustomerAddress, CustomerCity, CustomerState, CustomerZipcode, CustomerEmail, CustomerEmail2, CustomerPhoneNumber, CustomerPhoneNumberExt, CustomerType, CustomerSubscriptionType, CustomerCost, CustomerPaymentMethod, CustomerSignUpDate, CustomerPickUpDay, CustomerPickUpDay2, CustomerNotes FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerID);
                    con.Open();
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader["CustomerStatus"].ToString() == "New")
                            {
                                StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (reader["CustomerStatus"].ToString() == "Suspended")
                                {
                                    StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                                }
                            }
                            StatusLabel.Text = reader["CustomerStatus"].ToString();
                            if (reader["CustomerGroup"].ToString() == "")
                            {
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                GroupDropDown.SelectedValue = reader["CustomerGroup"].ToString();
                            }
                            txtCustomerFirstName.Text = reader["CustomerFirstName"].ToString();
                            txtCustomerLastName.Text = reader["CustomerLastName"].ToString();
                            txtCompanyName.Text = reader["CompanyName"].ToString();
                            txtCustomerAddress.Text = reader["CustomerAddress"].ToString();
                            txtCustomerCity.Text = reader["CustomerCity"].ToString();
                            txtCustomerState.Text = reader["CustomerState"].ToString();
                            txtCustomerZipcode.Text = reader["CustomerZipcode"].ToString();
                            txtCustomerEmail.Text = reader["CustomerEmail"].ToString();
                            if (reader["CustomerEmail2"].ToString() == "")
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Email2CheckBox.Checked = true;
                                txtCustomerEmail2.Visible = true;
                                txtCustomerEmail2.Text = reader["CustomerEmail2"].ToString();
                            }
                            txtCustomerPhoneNumber.Text = reader["CustomerPhoneNumber"].ToString();
                            txtCustomerPhoneNumberExt.Text = reader["CustomerPhoneNumberExt"].ToString();
                            CustomerType.SelectedValue = reader["CustomerType"].ToString();
                            SubscriptionType.SelectedValue = reader["CustomerSubscriptionType"].ToString();
                            CostTxtBx.Text = reader["CustomerCost"].ToString();
                            CustomerPaymentMethod.SelectedValue = reader["CustomerPaymentMethod"].ToString();
                            CustomerSignUpDate.Text = reader["CustomerSignUpDate"].ToString();
                            PickUpDay.SelectedValue = reader["CustomerPickUpDay"].ToString();
                            if (reader["CustomerPickUpDay2"].ToString() == "")
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PickUpDay2CheckBox.Checked = true;
                                PickUpDay2.Visible = true;
                                PickUpDay2.SelectedValue = reader["CustomerPickUpDay2"].ToString();
                            }
                            if (reader["CustomerNotes"].ToString() == "")
                            {
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string sqlfriendlyNotes = reader["CustomerNotes"].ToString().Replace("<br/>", "\n");

                                NotesTxtBx.Text = sqlfriendlyNotes;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void SaveCustomerChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Status = this.StatusLabel.Text;
            string Group = this.GroupDropDown.Text;
            string customerStatus = Status;
            string customerFirstName = this.txtCustomerFirstName.Text;
            string customerLastName = this.txtCustomerLastName.Text;
            string customerGroup = Group;
            string companyName = this.txtCompanyName.Text;
            string customerAddress = this.txtCustomerAddress.Text;
            string customerCity = this.txtCustomerCity.Text;
            string customerState = this.txtCustomerState.Text;
            string customerZipcode = this.txtCustomerZipcode.Text;
            string customerEmail = this.txtCustomerEmail.Text;
            string customerEmail2 = this.txtCustomerEmail2.Text;
            string customerPhoneNumber = this.txtCustomerPhoneNumber.Text;
            string customerPhoneNumberExt = this.txtCustomerPhoneNumberExt.Text;
            string customerType = this.CustomerType.Text;
            string customerSubscriptionType = this.SubscriptionType.Text;
            string customerCost = this.CostTxtBx.Text;
            string customerPaymentMethod = this.CustomerPaymentMethod.Text;
            string customerSignUpDate = this.CustomerSignUpDate.Text;
            string customerPickUpDay = this.PickUpDay.Text;
            string customerPickUpDay2 = this.PickUpDay2.Text;
            string customerNotes = this.NotesTxtBx.Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
            string strConnString1 = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString1))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET CustomerStatus=@CustomerStatus, CustomerGroup=@CustomerGroup, CustomerFirstName=@CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName=@CustomerLastName, CompanyName=@CompanyName, CustomerAddress=@CustomerAddress, CustomerCity=@CustomerCity, CustomerState=@CustomerState, CustomerZipcode=@CustomerZipcode, CustomerEmail=@CustomerEmail, CustomerEmail2=@CustomerEmail2, CustomerPhoneNumber=@CustomerPhoneNumber, CustomerPhoneNumberExt=@CustomerPhoneNumberExt, CustomerType=@CustomerType, CustomerSubscriptionType=@CustomerSubscriptionType, CustomerCost=@CustomerCost, CustomerPaymentMethod=@CustomerPaymentMethod, CustomerSignUpDate=@CustomerSignUpDate, CustomerPickUpDay=@CustomerPickUpDay, CustomerPickUpDay2=@CustomerPickUpDay2, CustomerNotes=@CustomerNotes WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerStatus", customerStatus);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerGroup", customerGroup);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerFirstName", customerFirstName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerLastName", customerLastName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", companyName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAddress", customerAddress);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerCity", customerCity);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerState", customerState);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerZipcode", customerZipcode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerEmail", customerEmail);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerEmail2", customerEmail2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPhoneNumber", customerPhoneNumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPhoneNumberExt", customerPhoneNumberExt);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", customerType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerSubscriptionType", customerSubscriptionType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerCost", customerCost);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPaymentMethod", customerPaymentMethod);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerSignUpDate", customerSignUpDate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPickUpDay", customerPickUpDay);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPickUpDay2", customerPickUpDay2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerNotes", customerNotes);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: the very first thing I'd do is turn on SQLProfiler and see what actually lands in the DB (assuming you're using SQL Server, that is).

Comment: I hope your submit button has the handler set like this onclick="SaveCustomerChanges_Click"

Comment: Are you sure that all the parameters are of text datatype? You add them with AddWitValue and this method looks to the value datatype to create the parameter. However some field names look of different kind (CustomerID, CustomerType, CustomerCost, SignUpDate)?

Comment: @AshwinSingh: It does, ha. The event fires, but the table just doesn't update... davek: How would one go about doing that? Would it even be possible for me since it is database from my host? I have gearhost, and it's running Microsoft SQL server 2008

Comment: @Steve Parameters are fine, I have another AddCustomer page, and it all gets added in correctly

Comment: think of separating your Data Access Logic to another Layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button click event handler `SaveCustomerChanges_Click` will occur after your `Page_Load` event handler. Your page load event handler is loading up your UI. You are updating the data after your UI has already loaded. You need to reload the UI after the update is performed ( think "DataBind" ).

See the following msdn article for an overview on the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Right, the page starts loading, looks up ID, fills in the info, I go ahead and make changes to textboxes, dropdowns, etc, click save and then the button does its thing. Since the button fires and goes through...shouldn't when it reloads, show the new data that was just entered?

Comment: The button event is handled when the page is posted back. The first time you ever load the page, you handle the page load event. Then the page is presented to the user. The user makes changes, and clicks the button. The page is posted back, and the page load event is handled again, and THEN the button event handler executes, updating the database. However, the page load code has already executed, so your UI is showing what is in the database before the update occurs.

Comment: Page_Load -> update data then click -> Page_Load -> SaveCustomerChanges_Click (what you save here?) use Page.IsPostBack == false conditional to load the page initial values.

Comment: yeah just added that, deploying as we speak, hope it works, thanks!